# Doing a LEFT JOIN, the matching value is lost from the result when it does not exist in the second table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

When I left join two tables like this:

```
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
```

if there is no matching row in *b*, then "id" is empty, although it exists in *a*.

How can I keep that value?

Comment: define "keep that value", please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really empty.  That is just how the results are interpreted by the tool you are using.  You see, the problem is that the result set has two columns called `id`, so one is arbitrarily chosen -- and it doesn't seem to be the one you want.

The simplest method is to switch to a `using` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM a LEFT JOIN
     b 
     USING (id);
```

This returns `id` only once in the result set and it should have the value in the first table (in this case).

Comment: @aquiros But I want to select table *b*, too, for those rows that have a matching row in the second table...

Comment: In that case, I think `SELECT a.*, b.* FROM...` would work. But I'm just querying in my head atm. Would you try it to confirm?

Comment: @aquinos At the moment I cannot. The missing row in table *b* has been created. I have to wait until there is a new row in table *a*. It is a live database.